# Deep linking with a specific format

Tags: android, android-studio, uri, android-manifest, deep-linking

I want to enable the deep linking to my app when click a URI having the following format:

```
http://abc-def?param=abc
```

Can it be achieved?

I've tried putting the following code in **AndroidManifest.xml**

```
<data android:scheme="http" android:host="abc-def"/>
```

I've tried also adding multiple regex in **pathPattern** but none of them worked.

Any help?

**EDIT**

Noting that with the solution above without any **pathPattern**, when clicking the URI without specifying any params, the deep linking works fine.

Comment: Your existing `<data>` element, as it stands, looks fine. How did you test this, to determine "none of them worked"?

Comment: Well I’ve sent an email (using gmail) to myself containing two URIs.. The first one is http://abc-def?param=abc. The second one is http://abc-def/?param=abc. Clicking both of them didn’t have the option to choose the app to open it through those URIs @CommonsWare

Comment: Did the URLs work without the query? (e.g., `http://abc-def`)

Comment: Your URL does not have a path (just a host, scheme, and query), so you definitely would not want `pathPattern`. Create a scrap app that creates an `ACTION_VIEW` `Intent` for your desired `Uri` (with query), and call `startActivity()` on that `Intent`. If your app comes up as an option (as you want), then Gmail is screwing up somewhere with URLs with queries. If your app does not come up (so you get the same behavior as Gmail), then Android itself would seem to be the culprit. I don't think there's anything you need in the manifest to say "I can haz query?".

Comment: Ok I'll try doing that now thanks @CommonsWare

Comment: Well well, it actually did work.. But is there any solution since the end user might click the link through different apps including Gmail maybe? @CommonsWare

Answer (score 1):

The problem with `http`-style app links is that not everyone handles them properly. For example, Chrome and Firefox (the last I checked, a few months ago) will not honor `http` app links at all, preferring instead to handle those links internally by requesting the indicated Web page. While I was not aware of Gmail's problems with URLs containing queries, it doesn't completely surprise me, though it's a bit odd.

For places where you provide actual HTML with actual links, using a custom scheme (e.g., `chrisapp://something`) may be more reliable. Browsers, for example, will realize that they have no idea how to handle the `chrisapp` scheme and are more likely to try `ACTION_VIEW`. However, in places where you are providing plain text (e.g., SMS), custom schemes are very unreliable, as it's unlikely that whoever presents the text will realize that this particular sequence of characters is something that should be clickable and open up an `ACTION_VIEW` activity.

If there is a universal, rock-solid way of doing app links, I am not aware of it. :-(